# What is the curve of the shape of a rubber sheet when a mass is dropped in the middle?

Tags: physics, curves, classical-mechanics

I've been working on trying to find or parametrise the equation of the curve one gets if one drops a mass, say a ball, on a rubber sheet. The shape would look like those popular analogies of gravity and general relativity which use rubber sheets to demonstrate the action of gravity.

To simplify matters, I considered the rubber to be two-dimensional and the weight to be infinitesimally  small. In addition, due to my limited knowledge of physics, the forces involved, and differential equations, my assumptions are mostly based on intuition and that limited knowledge of mechanics.

Now, by Hooke's law, the amount that the sheet will stretch is proportional to its extension, so if we consider a point $P$, with coordinates $(x, E(x))$ on our sheet, and consider only the force acting straight down, parallel to the force of gravity, we know that the the amount point $P$ sinks by, from its position without the weight, $E(x)$, will be proportional to that force.

$$F_P = k E_P$$ where E is the vertical "extension", how much point $P$ sinks by, and k is the constant of proportionality.

Moreover, the constant of proportionality will be constant throughout the sheet.

Now, we need to find what that force acting on $P$ is.

We know that the tension in the rubber should be the same everywhere, so at point $P$, the tension will act in the direction parallel to the gradient of the rubber sheet at point $P$. Therefore, to find the downwards force, we must find the vertical component of that tension vector.

This is just a force diagram problem, so solving it gives:

$$F_P = T \sin(\theta)$$ where T is the tension and $\theta$ is equal to $\arctan(E')$, where E' is the derivative of equation of the rubber, E, and the gradient at $P$.

By the identity $\sin(\arctan(x)) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$,

$$F_P = T \frac{E'}{\sqrt{E'^2 + 1}}  $$

But since the extension itself depends on $F$, we can get a differential equation:

$$E = \frac{T}{k} \frac{E'}{\sqrt{E'^2+1}} $$

I'd love to be able to solve this myself, and if someone could show me I'd be very grateful, but plugging this into Wolfram Alpha gives the solutions:

$$c+x=\sqrt{l^{2}-y^{2}}-l\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{l^{2}-y^{2}}}{l}\right)$$

and

$$c-x=\sqrt{l^{2}-y^{2}}-l\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{l^{2}-y^{2}}}{l}\right)$$

where $l = \frac{T}{k}$

Graphing these in desmos gives two curves which, when they intersect, seem to give a roughly correct-looking curve.

My questions are:

1. How can the differential equation be solved analytically?
2. What initial conditions am I missing to be able to eliminate $c$ and obtain a particular solution?
3. How do I relate $T$ to the weight of the ball in the middle, and does this affect the differential equation or provide us with initial conditions?

Comment: I think the shape should be approximately like the $3$-D view of the graph of $\dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$.

Comment: @Spectre what exactly do you mean by $3D$? The problem I'm considering is of a $2D$ cross-section, essentially, of a normal rubber sheet.

Comment: sorry then.. I thought you were looking for a 3D curve.. I didn't go through the whole question.

Comment: I don't agree with the way Hooke's Law is applied here. Hooke's Law is typically explainable by a linear relationship of stress and strain, i.e. force proportional to stretching; but the stretching of the rubber in this case is not proportional to the displacement from the unstressed position.

Comment: @David K How so? I'm considering the vertical component of that displacement vector at point P only, not the stretching of the whole thing.

Comment: That's your mistake. When you displace one point the whole thing stretches. Unless you account for that, your model has no connection with reality.

Comment: @David K If I consider each point as moving down and towards the centre, I can obtain the same differential equation by only considering the vertical component of that displacement vector? Because, really, a stretch of the sheet is simply a vertical and horizontal stretch, so I can decompose that vector into its components. How would you go about accounting for the stretching, if I haven't?

Comment: Try a simpler case: a rubber band stretched between two fixed points. You push the midpoint of the rubber band in a direction perpendicular to the line between the fixed points. If the initial length of the rubber band is $2L$, after deflecting it a distance $x$ at the center the length is $2\sqrt{L^2+x^2}.$ For a small deflection, the difference between this and $2L$ is proportional to $x^2$, not to $x.$

Comment: @David K This assumes that the elastic either side of the midpoint is straight, which would solve our problem immediately? Also I'm not looking for the extension of the elastic but how much it "extends" **downwards**. Therefore, the length of the elastic doesn't come into play. I'm afraid you haven't understood my problem. Would it be easier if I were to upload pictures?

Comment: "Therefore, the length of the elastic doesn't come into play." This cannot possibly be right. The reason Hooke's Law works (when it does) is because of Young's modulus, strain proportional to stress, and strain **is** the (change in the) length of the elastic. Only the deformation of the material, not its location in space, can explain the restoring force.

Comment: And yes, the rubber band is a simpler case than the entire sheet, but the point is that you can't blindly apply Hooke's Law to any displacement of any stretchy object. For the sheet we can assume circular symmetry around the mass and work out the strain and stress between concentric circles.

Comment: @David K My problem is essentially just that of the elastic band, I just couldn't put into words what I meant that well. However, how do you justify the elastic staying straight, and what are necessary calculations?

Comment: Doing a little more digging, I find that the sheet has different characteristics than the simple rubber band (no surprise there), and it appears it does have a linear deflection (surprise!) at the position of the weight after all: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433382 ... Next the question is the shape of the sheet, which apparently cannot be solved analytically: see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.3893.pdf